# Sql invoked Java methods and execution order

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I am currently working with sql invoked java functions in hsqldb.
This problem seems quite tricky and I guess it might be due to the execution order of the different parts of the sql statement. But I am hoping that someone knows another explanation to this.

The basic idea: 
I want to check if column "one" is larger than column "two" of table "A".

The problem:
I have to cast the string columns as integers. If there are cast problems the statement should not abort.

My solution (which does not work):
I select all rows which are safe to cast. These remaining rows are casted as int and can be compared.

Example:

```
select * from(
    select * from A INNER JOIN B ON A.num=B_num WHERE checkCast(A.one, B.type) = TRUE and checkCast(A.two, B.type) = TRUE
) WHERE cast(A.one as int) > cast(A.two as int)
```

checkCast is a Java function which is checking if the parameters A.one and A.two have got the correct format and range according to B.type

Edit: the tables look like this (everything varchar):

```
A
num    one    two
123    1      2
123    x      2

B
num    type
123    int500
```

Unfortunately, I get a SqlDataException from this. If I do the following it works:

1) replace B.type with a direct input (like this: checkCast(A.one, 'int500'))

2) alternatively do the comparison in a function which also uses B.type

I guess that somehow the outer select statement must somehow access data before the inner select statement is finished?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

This was asked and answered on the HSQLDB help forum:

https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/discussion/73674/thread/b246f577/

Basically the query optimiser decides when to evaluate each expression. You can replace the CHECKCAST function with a function written in SQL or JAVA to perform a comparison while taking into account any null values or values that cannot be cast by catching the exceptions internally and returning a result.